# I cant understand logic by print all 3-digit numbers having unique digits in the specified range

Tags: c

These are my past C language labwork mission and example outputs
[image]
text version :
In this lab work, you are required to print all 3-digit numbers having unique digits in the specified range.

Users must enter 2 integers from 1 to 8 inclusive.

Those integers will represent the lower and upper limit of the number’s digits.

You must implement main function and use 3 for loops to traverse all numbers for the specified range.
The main function:

• Ask 2 values from the user within a range of numbers from 1 to 8 inclusive:
lower (int) and upper (int): (10 pts)

• Implement 3 for loops (15 pts each)

• Print the numbers (25 pts)

• Print count of the numbers (20 pts)

[image]
MY FALSE OUTPUT

I try to make solve again but I cant.
Please describe my faults or tell the logic

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int low,high;
printf("Enter lowest digit\n");
scanf("%d",&low);
printf("Enter highest digit:\n");
scanf("%d",&high);
int a=low;
int b=low;
int c=low;
int i=high;
int j=high;
int k=high;
int counter =0;
for(a;a<i+1;a++)
{   printf("%d",a);
    for(b;b<j+1;b++)
    {
        printf("%d",b);
        for(c;c<k+1;c++)
            printf("%d",c);
        counter++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
printf("\n counter is %d",counter);
return 0;}
```

and this is my false output

[image]

Comment: Oh dear. This is going to sound strict, but there are some rules here. Please take the [tour], read [ask], delete your non-answer below. Add the code to your question, by [edit]ing it. Explain more about your problem. Describe the output you get in comparison to the one you want. Quote errors. Do not show pictures of code or other textual information, like assignments. For anything which is remotely like "Help me with homework please. " have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment . I  will consider your warning

Comment: Please apply consistent indentation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the compliment. Will try. Would be honored if you check later.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of *your own* attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: ı edited. main and #include problem just copy paste problem

Comment: And please don't post pictures of text. If the text is copyable tnhn please copy-paste it, else please rewrite it into the question. Images can't be copy-pasted from (which is sometimes helpful for us), they're not searchable (remember that this site isn't only for you right now), and they don't work with screen-readers.

Comment: Ferhat, well done moving the code into the question. Now you need to explain more about your problem. In which way does your code fail? Wrong output? No output? Crashes? Compiler errors? Please provide as much information as possible.

Comment: My code give wrong output you can check ı add my output and true output. I think ı have some problems for for loops. But ı can't sure

Comment: I think your assignment requires your to use `for` loops, instead of the `while` loops you used. Would you like to change your code and your question so that the solution will match the assignment or would you like to have answers which use your `while` loops to produce the correct output?

Comment: Using `for` loops in their most widely used form will automatically guide you a little closer to the right solution.

Comment: Actually, I tried to write with for loop for the first time, but I failed. It would be much better if I could write the code with for loop.

Comment: @Yunnosch okey ı try again

Comment: @Yunnosch ı rewrite my code using for loops and edited the post. But still ı have wrong output problem

Comment: Please check the first part of your for loops, the part between the `(` and the first `;`. You are missing something there. It is the answer to "can you spot?".

Comment: @Yunnosch  I hope you don't think I will just copy and paste the code. I am a first-class computer engineering student and I am not even taking this course right now. My only goal is to learn and practice. Thank you very much for saying that I chose the wrong loop in coding and giving me basic stackoverflow training. You are the coding hero :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define MIN 1
#define MAX 8


int print(int low, int high)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int first = low; first <= high; first++)
    {
        for(int second = low; second <= high; second++)
        {
            if(second == first) continue;
            for(int third = low; third <= high; third++)
            {
                if(third == first || third == second) continue;
                count++;
                printf("%d%d%d%c", first, second, third, (count % 8) ? ' ' : '\n');
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    int low, high, result;
    result = scanf("%d %d", &low, &high);
    if(result != 2 || low < MIN || low > MAX || high > MAX || high < MIN || low >= high)
    {
        printf("Wrong input\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Count: %d\n", print(low, high));
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eqfef6

Comment: Well thank you for providing an unexplained code-only in the middle of a homework process as recommended. You are making everything much harder.

Comment: today is my goodgivng day. At work I wrote the code for the new employee as well to not be sacked before the weekend.

Comment: So you are a "give a man a fish" person? I tend to teach fishing.

Comment: can you tell me why ı need the using  (count % 8) and my problem on printf statement location am ı right ?

Comment: And I thank everyone very much for their help. I am  so thankful for everyone

Comment: Ferhat, are you going to use that unexplained code? Then I can stop making an effort to help you learning to do it yourself. If you do make sure that you understand all details before handing in. Teachers tend to question students which provide code to homework assignments which they consider subtly beyond the students knowledge....

Comment: Of course not, I came here to learn. I asked the parts I don't understand in the code above. I am currently reviewing the code and will continue to ask for new parts that I do not understand.

Comment: I see. Then I will delete my partial answer below. Let me know if you decide to use my help. P__J__, over to you, please help by answering the upcoming questions. Alternatively really explain your code-only answer.

Comment: is   if(second == first) continue; statement using for obstruct same number such as 555 ? And  still ı can not understand this part : (count % 8) ? ' ' Why did we use this?

Comment: this prints new line if n*8 numbers we printed otherwise space.

Comment: ` if(second == first) continue;` if there is number already skip this iteration.

Comment: `So you are a "give a man a fish" person?` sometimes reading the code gives more knowledge

Comment: Now I get it PJ. I am trying to analyze the code and write myself right now thank you very much PJ  for your help.If  ı dont understand some parts ı write again. And @Yunnosch I hope you don't think I will just copy and paste the code. I am a first-class computer engineering student and I am not even taking this course right now. My only goal is to learn and practice. Thank you very much for saying that I chose the wrong loop in coding and giving me basic stackoverflow training.Thank you both very much. You're both trying to help someone with coding like me. This is a very honored behavior.

Comment: @FerhatAliTokuc You can't use `scanf()` correctly unless you **check the return**. E.g. `if (scanf("%d %d", &low, &high) != 2) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }` and you should also provide you user with a prompt for what information is needed so they are not left staring at a blinking cursor wondering what to do, e.g. `printf ("enter begin (%d <= begin <= %d) and end (begin < end <= %d): ", MIN, MAX, MAX);` before the call to `scanf()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your warning @DavidC.Rankin In the code I rewrite, I will fix that part.